# Sympy fails to find Fourier Transform of Complex Hyperbolic Secant (Sech) Function

Tags: python, sympy, symbolic-math

I'm trying to use Sympy to find the Fourier transform of a hyperbolic secant function ("Sech") with a complex argument.

```
import sympy as sy
C, t, T0, f, w = sy.symbols('C, T, T_0, f, omega', real=True)
Ut = sy.sech(t/T0) * sy.exp(-sy.sqrt(-1) * C / 2 * t * t / (T0 * T0))
Uf = sy.fourier_transform(Ut, t, f)
```

Unfortunately, Sympy seems to simply hang when I request this.

Is this a bug or is there a better way I could present the request to sympy?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

It's a bug, unfortunately. SymPy cannot handle the integral, and it gets stuck in the integration algorithm.